# Text input on a Turtle based Python Game

Tags: python

I am trying to create a turtle based, text adventure game with an interactive GUI. But I ran into a problem. In the image attached, you will see a ">" and then after that, I would like the user to be able to type a command, and submit it to determine the path of a game. I am relatively new to python, so I am not familiar with external libraries or modules that could help with this.

```py
import os
import turtle

#SCREEN
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Untitled Game")


#Box
box = turtle.Turtle()
box.color("white")
box.speed(0)
box.penup()
box.setposition(-500, -200)
box.pensize(5)
box.pendown()
box.fd(900)

#TEXT IN TEXT BOX
text = turtle.Turtle()
text.speed(0)
text.color("white")
text.penup()
text.setposition(-350, 300)
text.write("This is a test", False, align="left", font=("Helvetica", 25, "normal"))
text.hideturtle()


#TEXT ARROW
arrow = turtle.Turtle()
arrow.speed(0)
arrow.color("white")
arrow.penup()
arrow.setposition(-360, -300)
arrow.pendown()
arrow.pensize(4)
arrow.write(">", False, align="left", font=("Helvetica", 60, "normal"))

screen.mainloop()
```

[What it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW20g.png)

Comment: woooah `import turtle` is a thing?

Comment: This is a situation where I would used *embedded* turtle instead of *standalone* turtle.  That is, make this a tkinter interface with an embedded turtle canvas but use a tkinter `Text` or `Entry` widget outside the turtle canvas to get input from the user.